# <router-outlet> is displaying and entire page even when not called

Tags: angular

When I put my  in the home component or home.component.html, it displays the page again so that I have 2 versions of the same page on top of each other.

EDIT: I've tried to give router-outlet a name and it seems to solve the current issue but then whenever I try to go onto /articles, it redirects back to home page

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="app-component">
  <nav>
<div class="logo">
  <img class="home-button" src="./assets/images/3d-printer.png" alt="home button">
</div>
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="toggle()">blog page</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/articles" routerLinkActive="active">all articles</a></li>
  <li>contact</li>
</ul>
<div class="logo">
  <h4>logo</h4>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="title-container">
  <div class="title">
    My blog about things
  </div>
</div>

<app-home></app-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<div class="footer">
  <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/3d-printing" title="3d printing icons">3d printing icons created by
    Freepik - Flaticon</a>
</div>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      component: AppComponent,
  },
  {
      path: 'timeline',
      component: TimelineComponent,
  },
{
    path: 'article',
    component: articleComponent,
},
{
    path: 'allarticles',
    component: AllarticlesComponent,
},

{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/'
}
];
  
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I linked to /articles in a ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `AppComponent` Component listed as your default `''` route. So it basically renders the `AppComponent` inside itself, thus repeating the `AppHome` Component.

To mitigate this, you could delete the `<app-home>` component from your `AppComponent`'s template and instead render it via the router:

###### app.component.html

```
<app-home></app-home> <-- DELETE THIS
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

###### app-routing.module.ts

```
  {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent, // <-- Instead of AppComponent
  },
```